# Passing object as a parameter on an onClick function

Tags: javascript

I want to pass an object to onclick function as parameter. Then I will call that parameter into the function and push into empty array. But I tried it all, it just push id, name etc. I want to pass `laundryValue[i]` whole array on `onclick="getLaundryClick()` as parameter.

```js
    var laundryValue = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Sunglasses', price: 25},
        {id: 2, name: 'Jeans', price: 10},
        {id: 3, name: 'Shirts', price: 15},
        {id: 4, name: 'Cables', price: 20}
    ]
    
    var newLaundryValue = [];

    for (var i in laundryValue) {
        var wrap = laundryValue[i];
        document.getElementById('laundry-value').innerHTML += 
        '<li>' + 
            '<div class="laundry-name">' + laundryValue[i].name + '</div>' + 
            '<div class="laundry-price">' + laundryValue[i].price + '</div>' + 
            '<button class="laundry-btn" onclick="getLaundryClick(' + [wrap] + ')">' + 'Add' + '</button>' +  
        '</li>';
        
    }
    
    function getLaundryClick(wrap) {
        console.log(wrap)
    }
```

Comment: you should pass an Id as parameter that makes reference to the object. that object might be stored in localstore then when you click on the function you can find the object using the Id searching into localstore. LocalStore is a global place to save data.

Comment: your console.log returns [object Object]?

Comment: @José Nope it say `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: if you are always going to have the object in memory I would pass an index only, otherwise I would pass JSON.stringify ([wrap]), although the latter is a bit dirty, in any case the correct form would be document.createElement and then to that add element in event listener

Comment: onclick="getLaundryClick(' + JSON.stringify ([wrap]) + ')">' try this and in the function do parse

Comment: @José Not done, still giving error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to convert the object to a string and use `JSON.parse` in the onclick handler to convert it back.

```
'<button class="laundry-btn" onclick="getLaundryClick(JSON.parse(\'' 
   + JSON.stringify(wrap).replace(/'/g, '&apos;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '\'))">' 
   + 'Add' + '</button>'
```

Comment: Same as the OP is getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Thanks for informing me. I forgot to add the quotes.

Comment: Still does not work. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: Nice work. Working now. I was about to post answer with `.replace` as well.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Thanks for the help. I am currently unable to test, so it took a while to figure it out.

Comment: Thumbs up for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class to create buttons dynamically from an array by this way:
You can set the print method inside this class to access any value of any element of your array.

```js
var laundryValue = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Sunglasses', price: 25},
        {id: 2, name: 'Jeans', price: 10},
        {id: 3, name: 'Shirts', price: 15},
        {id: 4, name: 'Cables', price: 20}
];
    
class ButtonToPress {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.obj = obj;

    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.onclick = this.print.bind(this);
    button.innerText = this.obj.name;

    document.getElementById('laundry-value').appendChild(button);
  }

  print() {
    console.log(this.obj.name, this.obj.price);
  }
}


let buttons = [];
for (let i = 0; i < laundryValue.length; i++) {
  buttons[i] = new ButtonToPress(laundryValue[i]);
}
```

```html
  <div id="laundry-value"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is just to play around with single and double quotes `PAIR` so it would not conflict as we are passing here a quoted string, we need to consider how it is rendered as in it's HTML form:

**Working Simplified Version:**

```js
var laundryValue = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Sunglasses', price: 25},
        {id: 2, name: 'Jeans', price: 10},
        {id: 3, name: 'Shirts', price: 15},
        {id: 4, name: 'Cables', price: 20}
    ]
    
    var newLaundryValue = [];

    for (var i in laundryValue) {
        var wrap = laundryValue[i];
        
        wrap =  JSON.stringify(wrap)
       
        document.getElementById('laundry-value').innerHTML += 
        '<li>' + 
            '<div class="laundry-name">' + laundryValue[i].name + '</div>' + 
            '<div class="laundry-price">' + laundryValue[i].price + '</div>' + 
            '<button class="laundry-btn" onclick=\'getLaundryClick(' + wrap+' ) \'>' + 'Add' + '</button>' +  
        '</li>';
        
    }
    
    function getLaundryClick(wrap) {
        console.log(wrap)
    }
```

```html
<div id="laundry-value">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I wrote the complete code. Here I just used the laundaryValue array for looping and stored it in a variable, then binded on html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="laundry-value"></div>

    <button onclick="getLaundryClick()">Get Laundary</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        let  laundryValue = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Sunglasses', price: 25},
        {id: 2, name: 'Jeans', price: 10},
        {id: 3, name: 'Shirts', price: 15},
        {id: 4, name: 'Cables', price: 20}
    ]
    let loopData = '';

    function getLaundryClick(){
        for (let i = 0; i < laundryValue.length; i++) {
            let addObj = JSON.stringify(laundryValue[i]);

            loopData += 
                `
            <ul>
                <li>ID: ${laundryValue[i].id}</li>
                <li>Name: ${laundryValue[i].name}</li>
                <li>Price: ${laundryValue[i].price}</li>
                <li><button onclick='addObjectFunction(${JSON.stringify(laundryValue[i])})'>Add</button></li>
            </ul>
            `;
        }

        document.getElementById('laundry-value').innerHTML = loopData;
    }

    function addObjectFunction(params){
        console.log(params)
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions with `JSON.parse()` will work. However, you can achieve the same thing with less effort:

```js
const laundryValue = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Sunglasses', price: 25},
        {id: 2, name: 'Jeans', price: 10},
        {id: 3, name: 'Shirts', price: 15},
        {id: 4, name: 'Cables', price: 20} ];
 var newLaundryValue = [];

 document.getElementById('laundry-value').innerHTML = laundryValue.map((wrap,i)=>
        `<li><div class="laundry-name">${wrap.name}</div>
            <div class="laundry-price">${wrap.price}</div>
            <button class="laundry-btn" data-id="${i}">Add</button> 
         </li>`
 ).join('\n');
    
document.onclick=function(ev){ let el=ev.target; // global click handler ...
  if (el.classList.contains('laundry-btn')){let itm=laundryValue[el.dataset.id];
    newLaundryValue.push(itm)
    console.log(`added ${itm.name} to cart.`)
  } else if (el.classList.contains('cart'))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newLaundryValue)); 
}
```

```css
li div {display: inline-block; margin:4px 8px}
```

```html
<div id="laundry-value"></div>
<hr><button class="cart">show cart</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

**CASE 1**

```js
 var laundryValue = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Sunglasses', price: 25},
        {id: 2, name: 'Jeans', price: 10},
        {id: 3, name: 'Shirts', price: 15},
        {id: 4, name: 'Cables', price: 20}
    ]
    
    var newLaundryValue = [];

    for (var i in laundryValue) {
        var wrap = laundryValue[i];
        var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(wrap));
        document.getElementById('laundry-value').innerHTML += 
        '<li>' + 
            '<div class="laundry-name">' + laundryValue[i].name + '</div>' + 
            '<div class="laundry-price">' + laundryValue[i].price + '</div>' + 
            '<button class="laundry-btn" onclick="getLaundryClick(JSON.parse(\'' 
   + JSON.stringify(wrap).replace(/'/g, '&apos;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '\'))">' 
   + 'Add' + '</button>' +  
        '</li>';
        
    }
    
    function getLaundryClick(wrap) {
        console.log(wrap);
    }
```

```html
 <div id="laundry-value"></div>
```

**CASE 2**

See working example..

```js
var laundryValue = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Sunglasses', price: 25},
        {id: 2, name: 'Jeans', price: 10},
        {id: 3, name: 'Shirts', price: 15},
        {id: 4, name: 'Cables', price: 20}
];
    
class ButtonToPress {
  constructor(obj) {
    this.object = obj;

    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.onclick = this.print.bind(this);
    button.innerText = this.object.name;

    document.getElementById('laundry-value').appendChild(button);
  }

  print() {
    console.log(this.object);
  }
}


let buttons = [];
for (let i = 0; i < laundryValue.length; i++) {
  buttons[i] = new ButtonToPress(laundryValue[i]);
}
```

```css
button{
margin: 0 5px;
background: #0095ff;
border:none;
padding: 5px 10px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="laundry-value"></div>
```

Comment: Thats not what the OP wanted. Read the question again please :)